# Logging Desktop App Usage with HTTPRequest

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms, ashx

I'm trying to track the usage of a winforms app (username and time launched) installed on our users' devices.  I know that IIS has strong logging capabilities, but what I'm really after is the name of the specific user (Windows logon) using the app.

So far, I've set up an .ashx web handler that the app makes a request to (every time its started on a client device), with the username appended as a querystring parameter (using Environment.UserName).  The ashx handler gets the request and logs the username with a timestamp to a database.  Everything is working great, but I can't help but wonder if this is the "right" or "best practice" way of doing things.

I'm not one of those guys that says "Well, it works so that's good enough"...I won't be able to sleep at all if I don't feel 100% great about our implementation.  Is there a more legitimate way of doing this?  WCF, for instance?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I just re-read my post and feel like I should clarify that this is an internal tool used by our employees.

Comment: why don't you simply do that logging in winforms app ?

Comment: Hmm..maybe I don't understand your question. How would I read the usage logs if it gets recorded on the client and never transmitted to the server?

Comment: so you can't access log database from winforms app ? OK, that's the legitimate reason :), but it wasn't clear from original post. At least to me

Comment: Employee can block this with firewall, and run app without log, if don't check response in winforms app. If that is even important, it's not clear what is the purpose of that log.

Comment: @AntonioBakula: The app won't start if the employee isn't connected to the internet, because it downloads its internal functionality every time it starts (javascript)-- so I'm not too worried about HTTP requests being blocked.